# Dreaded Image Border Radius in Safari

Tags: image, safari, border, css

I know this has been asked and answered a million times over, but each solution seems to be a little different and I can't seem to get any of the scores of posts I've read to work for me.

I'm building a WooCommerce enabled site and am having problems with the image border radius in Safari. I'm pretty new to CSS and envisioning the scale of the problem and solution is escaping me. Since this is a pretty common problem, I'll be brief.

Here's the layout:

- setting up my store with Woothemes
- I've set an image border radius to my thumbs in the store
- it looks great in Firefox, looks crap in Safari.
- I simply can't figure out how to make it work using the solutions I've been reading out about. I'm sure there's something simple I just haven't grasped yet.

Here's the link to the store: http://printologie.com/shop/ - and a single product page which presents the same issue: http://printologie.com/shop/akuafoil-cards/

and here's the code from my custom.css (the simple -webkit tag doesn't seem to fix it):

```
ul.products li a img {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 80px 60px 80px 60px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0.75em;
    padding: 4%;
    width: 91%;
}
```

Thanks for any thoughts and explanations of fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Border radius is a css3 property. So if you are using for your project then you have to add all vendor prefix. Like for opera `-o-`, for chrome and safari `-webkit-`, for Firefox `-moz-`, and for the Microsoft `-ms-`.

So your property will look like:

```
-webkit-border-radius:80px 60px 80px 60px;
-moz-border-radius:80px 60px 80px 60px;
-o-border-radius:80px 60px 80px 60px;
-ms-border-radius:80px 60px 80px 60px;
border-radius:80px 60px 80px 60px;
```

Comment: Right!  So this is exactly what I've been trying based on all I've read and it's not working....

After adding the vendor prefixes, same problem, no change : http://printologie.com/shop/